# Trying to create Javascript form to calculate end times

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a form that users can fill out to calculate a projected project end time (think time punches).

For example:
You're projected to spend 8 hours on a project, you start that project at 8 am and you'll have 1 hour of downtime that doesn't count towards project time in the middle.
8am start + 8 hour projection + 1 hour delay = Projected End Time of 5pm.

I'm a novice at best with Javascript though I can typically find a similar script online and cannibalize then rewrite it for my needs. In this instance though, I feel like I'm out of my depth by a long shot, as the closest I could get was a script that adds 2 boxes together but doesn't account for time (so 8+9=17, not 5 like I needed).

Any help would be greatly appreciated! If need be I can paste the script I was trying to edit, though I'm pretty sure it's useless. I tried to Google how to write this basic thing I want to use but after 3 hours and no progress I decided to cave in and ask.

Thanks for taking the time to read!

Comment: What an excellent time to not reinvent the wheel seeing as we have [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: @h2ooooooo That is one nice lib

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your overall calculation, but if you want to account for AM/PM time in your result you simply subtract 12 hours from the result.  17-12 = 5 PM.

Here is a rough sample...

```
var time = 17;

AmPmTime(17);   //  5 PM

function AmPmTime(t) {
  var result = t + " AM";

  if (t > 12) {
      result = (t-12) + " PM";
  } else if (t == 0)
      result = "12 AM";
  } 

  return result;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! After reading through the site I'm realizing I don't know enough about JS to really utilize a lot of what's been offered, so I'll have to try and cobble html coding together or something. Thank you very much for the info though, I appreciate it.